# how to run php when button is clicked?

Tags: php, html

I want to run a php page when the submit button is clicked, here is my code:

```
    echo "<tr><td colspan=3>
    <form method='post'><table><tr><td>
    <h4>Quantity</h4></td><td><input type=text name='qnt' /></td><td>
    <input type='button' value='Add to card' name='buy' /></td></tr></table>
    </form>
    </td></tr>";

      if(isset($_POST['buy'])){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('successful'); </script>";
    include("addtocard.php");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with some of the things that have already been mentioned, including what was said in a [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665444/how-to-run-php-when-button-is-clicked#comment32748776_21665491), regarding including the Quantity entered in the form's input.

***Sidenote:*** Not knowing what is inside the `addtocard.php` file, I used my own basic codes to produce (reproduce) a successful test. Notes are included further below.

**Using:**

```
<?php
    echo "<tr><td colspan=3>
    <form method='post'><table><tr><td>
    <h4>Quantity</h4></td><td><input type=text name='qnt' /></td><td>
    <input type='submit' value='Add to card' name='buy' /></td></tr></table>
    </form>
    </td></tr>";

      if(isset($_POST['buy'])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('successful'); </script>";
    include("addtocard.php");

}
```

**Sidenote:** You could also add `action=''` for the form's action.

I.e.: `<form method='post' action=''>` that will submit as "self".

And the following inside `addtocard.php` which I took upon myself to test with, producing a successful result.

```
<?php
$qnt = $_POST['qnt'];
echo "Quantity: " . $qnt;
```

and entering the number 100 inside the form, did in fact echo `100` and it did produce a popup alert of `successful` also.

You could also use an added conditional statement to check if the submit button is set, and that a quantity was entered:

```
<?php
    echo "<tr><td colspan=3>
    <form method='post'><table><tr><td>
    <h4>Quantity</h4></td><td><input type=text name='qnt' /></td><td>
    <input type='submit' value='Add to card' name='buy' /></td></tr></table>
    </form>
    </td></tr>";

      if(isset($_POST['buy']) && !empty($_POST['qnt'])){

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('successful'); </script>";
include("addtocard.php");
}
else {
echo "Enter a quantity.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely safe, there should be two changes:

```
  <form method='post'>
```

Should have an action attribute, pointing to the location of the file on the server  ie.

```
<form method='post' action="/myfile.php">
```

also:

```
<input type='button' value='Add to card' name='buy' />
```

Should be

```
<input type='submit' value='Add to card' name='buy' />
```

Comment: I did it, but I still have the same problem..didn't work

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer. I tested your code with Crispen's answer, and it worked. Plus, your posted code doesn't have `<?php` so if you don't have those or are including this from another file, run your posted code "as is" with `button` changed to `submit` @user3194430 - And define "didn't work". Are you trying to echo the "Quantity" in the input box? My guess is that you're trying to echo the Quantity into `addtocard.php`, right? If so, show us what is inside `addtocard.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes you are right, I'am trying to post the Quantity into `addtocard.php`. btw I did the same way in another page and it worked successfully, but in this code, when I click the submit button the page reloads

Comment: Then something else is breaking your code. Is is possible for you to post what you have in that file? @user3194430

Answer (score 1):

It appears that several others have taken a poke at answering this, but I think they're missing the fundamental problem with your code here. PHP does not run on the client side, only on the server side. You'll need to (as other's have stated) actually submit the form to a PHP service to inspect the values a user enters into your form.

You may want to read a bit more about how PHP works, it can be kind of confusing since it outputs HTML, but isn't present at all on the actual web page your users see. [This link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php) from the PHP docs might help a bit.

Comment: Honestly, I should have commented on this, but I didn't even grasp that there was broken understanding there.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type='button' value='Add to card' name='buy' />
```

to

```
<input type='submit' value='Add to card' name='buy' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might possibly want to change the value from "button" to "submit" it might work. Good luck and here is an example:

```
<input type="submit" value='Add to card' name="buy" action= "<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"/>
```

**EDIT:**
The user below talked about the action, totally forgot, but, your code seems to interigrate it into the file, therefore you can use this example. Good luck.

**EDIT 2:**
PHP_SELF has an exploit I totally forgot about. I have updated the code with it. And what is wrong with the code? It seems fine.